# cakephp show validation errors with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.0 and I'm having problem using Cake's validation thing, which works wonderful when used for it alone.

```
var $validate = array(
        'loginname' => array(
            'minCharactersRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 3),
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'on' => 'create',
            ),
            'alphaNumericRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            ),
            'uniqueRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
            ),
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'minCharactersRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 5),
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
            ),
                    // on so on ...
```

Due to Internalization I put the error messages into the view like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('display_name', array(
// some other options ...
'error' => array(
    'betweenRule' => __('Your Dispay Name must contain at least 3 characters and should be maximal 20 characters long.'),
    'uniqueRule' => __('This Display Name is already in use!'),
                                            ),
);
```

Now I want jQuery to validate the form on client-side as well with some little - sexy message box to return validation errors if something goes wrong.

The Ajax Request works fine but the problem here is: I only get returned the name of the validation rule, not the message. 
sure: Because I didn't specified any messages in the model.

But how can I get those messages I declared in the view?
Is there any solution without having to type everything twice (PHP and JS)?